# onitemclicklistener for items of list view is not working

Tags: android

I am assigning action to the item of list view in the below code .But when I am clicking Item of list view application is "unfortunately stopping". I am providing the code below.

```
package com.lara;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FamilyActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;
    private String  names[]={"sum","hari","mom","dad"};
    private ArrayAdapter<String> s1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.family1);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        s1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(), R.layout.text, names);
        lv.setAdapter(s1);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), 555, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: can you post stack trace

Answer (score 3):

Try the below

```
s1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(FamilyActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
```

and change Toast to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ 555, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

or

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(555), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

555 is an int value

`public static Toast makeText (Context context, int resId, int duration)`

looks for a resource with the id provided if not found you get resource not found exception

What you need

`public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)`

So use a string

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this

```
Toast.makeText(FamilyActivity.this, ""+500, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Application is stopping because 
below are the arguments you need to pass in order to show a Toast.

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

but you are passing `555` which is `Integer` not `CharSequence`

Update your code like this

```
  s1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.text, names);
```

and

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+555, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I agree with Brontok, you need to change the type of second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what is in that `R.layout.text` layout?? Run the program with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item1` (something like that) and see if it crashes. Secondly since you are extending class Activity where there is getApplication I think you can also use `this` keyword. Also the docs for the Toast.makeText method show that the second argument is a string so using @Raghunandan 's method might just do the trick. One last point is please always provide the logcat post,I didnt know how to use it and would bother everyone here on S/O with simple meagre stuff but once u learn to use it debugging will be easy,make it a point to learn how to use